# Pass empty string as nullable int property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My model:

```
[DisplayName("Height")]
public int? Height { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Width")]
public int? Width { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Width) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Height) %>
```

Action:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    SaveSettings(model);
```

When empty strings are passed from view, the ModelState is false, but I need empty strings to be valid input, so that **nulls** are passed and ModelState.IsValid will be true. What can I add to the view to add this logic ? Or perhaps any other solution ? Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are work arounds, such as using a string property on your ViewModel and using a RegEx validator to make sure it is a number. The Regex shouldn't fire on an empty input. Then when you go from ViewModel to Model you'll have to do a conditional on the string value like

```
 var m = new Model();
 m.Property = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Property)? int.parse(this.Property) as int?:null;
```

Answer (score 0):

`int?` (`Nullable<int>`) will never be able to accept an empty string.  And empty string is neither `null` or an `int` value (which are the demands of `Nullable<int>`).

If you want to intercept this behavior you can design your own custom model binder by either implementing `IModelBinder` or subclass `DefaultModelBinder`.  Doing this, you can set an empty string value equal to `null` (or some magic number, but I'd prefer `null`).